# Inquiry Regarding Customizing and Sharing Backlog Views in Azure DevOps

Tags: view, backlog

Currently, we are using Azure DevOps for our project management, and we find the backlog view to be a crucial aspect of our workflow. We are interested in exploring the possibility of customizing the backlog view to better suit our team's specific needs. Specifically, we are wondering if there is a way to customize the backlog view and whether these customizations can be shared with other users within our organization. If there are any features, extensions, or recommended practices for achieving this customization, we would greatly appreciate your guidance.